# Navigation to the webpage was canceled

Tags: 2013

I have SharePoint 2013, I can't create a new page, I getting 
**Navigation to the webpage was canceled**

[image]

P.S. I'm already SharePoint Administrator

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: yes Firefox,IE,chrome

Comment: Ok, which version of IE you are using and do you have any antivirus installed on your machine? Are you the only one who is facing this issue in your peers?

Comment: it's IE 11, all users are facing  this problem!

Comment: Try this: In Internet Explorer, click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options. Click the Security tab, and then click the Custom Level button. In the "Security Settings" dialog box, scroll to the "Display mixed content" setting in the "Miscellaneous" section (about 55% of the way down), and then click Enable. Source: https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=13272

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved  through IISRESET